# Undeleted answer doesn't reappear in the listing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers

I posted an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949796/jsf-custom-selectitems). I initially interpreted that OP was using `<h:selectManyMenu>` and my answer was targeted on that. After posting it and re-reading the question once more, I had a %@#$ moment, deleted the answer, thought a sec about the solution, edited the answer and then undeleted it. All within the 5 minute grace period. It got upvoted and accepted as well.

However, the question in question with the title "Jsf custom selectItems" remains unanswered in the [tag listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0) and [OP's question history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286999/la-chamelle).

---

[image]

---

Did something fail during the undelete?

Comment: Nice work! [Now the question doesn't even have answer sorting tabs](http://i.imgur.com/9YA3C.png "What, no freehand circles? They're there, but like the things that are being circled, they are not visible.").

Comment: @Grace: omg, didn't notice that!

Comment: It's time to spin the wheel of blame !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There was a bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/wrong-answer-count-after-an-answer-was-deleted-and-undeleted/1634#1634) around undeleting answers; this has been fixed and deployed.